# How to organize a sentence which contains English and Hebrew?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to insert my DB a string that contains both English and Hebrew, but it mixed the sentence,
for example: I'm writing
"קקקקקקקקקקקק English word ככככככככככככככככ"
but in DB I see it like that:
"ככככככככככככככככ English word קקקקקקקקקקקק"
What can be the reason and how can I fix it?
important point:

- before inserting I'm converting it from utf8 to ascii and doing str_pad to left

That's my code:

```
$row = trim(@iconv("UTF8", "ISO8859-8", $input));
```

and before inserting:

```
$element = str_pad($element, $length, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

that's the only rows that can be the reason.

Comment: Don't just describe your code, show it to us

Comment: Check 'Collation' of column table

Comment: I added code, do you see something wrong?

Comment: Since you think these two lines might be the problem, have you done any debugging to look at the string before and after each of them? Break the problem down: don't start looking at the DB if you think the problem is in the PHP code. (Also, a side note: ISO 8859-8 is not the same thing as ASCII. It has roughly as much in common with it as UTF-8 does.)

Comment: Could it have anything to do with RTL versus LTR?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: You are right! that was my problem